# Compress .tar.gz without directories in Perl script

Tags: bash, perl, tar

Seems like a stupid question, but I can't find anything via google or man page...I'm sure it's something with my quotes...When I run the following from the command line, it runs as expected/desired(i.e. only files without any directories):

```
tar cfz /path/to/file.tar.gz --directory="/path/to/" .
```

However, I have this analogous line in perl, albeit with a variable as the path ($folder_errors='/path/to'):

```
system('tar cfz '."\"${folder_errors}\"/errors.tar.gz --directory=\"\"${folder_errors}\"/\" .");
```

also tried

```
system('tar cfz '."\"${folder_errors}\"/errors.tar.gz --directory=\"${folder_errors}\"/ .");
```

with the same (unexpected) results.

It compresses the correct files, however, inside of the compressed file is the file structure `./` where all of the files reside.

Comment: What's up with those weird double double-quotes?

Comment: @melpomene I'd be lying if I claimed to be "quote" knowledgeable.  I did remove the doubles b/c i saw the same behavior.  I was really just trying things.  I'm new to perl and bash and still not clear on quote implementations.

Comment: @ikegami i ran the debugger (perl -d) and checked the variable just before that line executed.  The correct files are in the compressed file, which also lands in the desired directory.  The only issue is that the files inside of the tarball are inside of `./`

Comment: When I use that command, I get `./foo ./bar ./bar/baz`. whether from command-line or from Perl. I call into question your claim that you don't have a leading `./` when you create the archive from the command line.

Comment: @ikegami i'll check again.

Comment: One possibility is that you have an alias for `tar` that adds an option to remove the leading `./`, but I find that unlikely. Try running `type tar` from the command line.

Comment: @ikegami it looks like you're correct.  I was viewing the file inside of gmail b/c this eventually gets sent via e-mail and it shows `./`.  However, when I opened the file in the terminal, it's as expected.  In an effort to salvage embarrassment, what did you mean about injection bugs in your other comment?  Having a variable name turn into an executable?

Comment: Adding double quotes around a string is not sufficient to correctly convert a string into a shell literal. String::ShellQuote can be used, or you can avoid the shell entirely, for example, by using multi-arg `system`: `system('tar', 'cfz', "$folder_errors/errors.tar.gz", "--directory=$folder_errors")`

Comment: "inside of the compressed file is the file structure ./ where all of the files reside." is unclear. Could you gives the result of tar tvf /path/to/errors.tar.gz ?

Comment: @BOC this has been resolved.  It was an idiot error on my part.  Gmail actually shows the ./ directory when you open the tar.gz file.  When opened from the command line, it behaves as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Try perl's quote operators. `qq[...]` acts like double-quotes, except you don't have to escape the literal `"` inside them.

```
system qq[tar cfz "$folder_errors/errors.tar.gz" --directory="$folder_errors"];
```

Comment: While your version is cleaner, it's functionally identical to the OP's second non-working snippet. /// It also suffers from the same (easily avoided) injection bugs as the OP!

Comment: Thanks, the code is now more readable, but still suffers the same problem that I had.

Answer (score -1):

Your quotes seem corrects. Have you noticed that you are creating the tar.gz in the same directory where files to archives reside? I think you are exposing yourself to troubles. If you can not change the target directory of tar, you should avoid recursion with:

```
system qq[tar cfz "$folder_errors/errors.tar.gz" --exclude "./errors.tar.gz" --directory="$folder_errors" . ];
```